# Find the surface area of a hemisphere cut off by a cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the surface area of a hemisphere of radius 1 cut off by a cylinder having this radius as diameter.

I did:
Equations for the hemisphere and cylinder are given respectively by
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$
$$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+y^2=\frac{1}{4}$$
Since 
$$z_x=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$$
and $$z_y=\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$$
So the required surface is 
$$
\begin{align}
S&=\iint_R \sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}dx dy\\
& =\iint_R \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}}dxdy\\
&=\int^{{\pi}/{2}}_{{-\pi}/{2}}\int^{\cos \theta}_0\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}drd\theta\\
&=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\left[-\sqrt{1-r^2}\bigg|^{\cos \theta}_0\right]d\theta\\
&=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}(1-\sin \theta)d\theta\\
&=\pi
\end{align}
$$
However, the solution used the exact same argument, except when doing change of variable, by using symmetry, the integration $\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} \cdots d\theta$ can be reduced to $2\int^{\pi/2}_0 \cdots d\theta$, and in the end, it gave $\pi-2$ as a solution.